# How do I create a Vec of Tuples holding references?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I need to call a function that accepts an argument of this type:

```rust
 &mut Vec<(&A,&mut B)>
```

Types A and B are `Clone` but not `Copy`.

I am iterating over a Vec of a different type and constructing the A and B objects. Then I want to put their references into Tuples and push all the tuples into a Vec. After the loop completes I will pass the created Vec in a call to another method (**CompiledExpression::for_loops**).

I get the dreaded errors `creates a temporary which is freed while still in use` and `borrowed value does not live long enough`.

I tried hoisting a let binding out of the loop to hold the A and B objects, but that causes a different error.

Here is a code snippet:

```rust
    fn walk_for_expression(&mut self, in_expressions: &Pair<'a, Rule>, inner_expression: &Pair<'a, Rule>, expr: &mut CompiledExpression) -> Result<(), String> {
        let mut inner_expr = CompiledExpression::new("inner");
        let r1 = self.walk_tree(inner_expression, &mut inner_expr);
        if let Err(message) = r1 {
            return Err(format!("Unable to parse body of for-expression {}. {}", inner_expression.as_str(), message));
        }

        let mut in_expr_children = self.children(in_expressions);

        let mut loop_vars_with_expressions: Vec<(&FeelValue, &mut CompiledExpression)> = Vec::new();
        for in_expr in &in_expr_children {
            // Assume: in_expression = name ~ in_token ~ expression
            let mut in_expr_parts = self.children(in_expr);
            // let mut loop_variable = FeelValue::Name(QName::from_str(in_expr_parts[0].as_str()).unwrap());
            let mut loop_expr = CompiledExpression::new("loop-expression");
            let r2 = self.walk_tree(&in_expr_parts[2], &mut loop_expr);

            if let Err(message) = r2 {
                return Err(format!("Unable to parse for-expression's loop expression {}. {}", in_expr_parts[2].as_str(), message));
            }
            loop_vars_with_expressions.push((
                // ERRORS ON NEXT TWO LINES:
                &FeelValue::Name(QName::from_str(in_expr_parts[0].as_str()).unwrap()),
                &mut loop_expr
            ));
        }
        let mut for_expr = CompiledExpression::for_loops(&mut loop_vars_with_expressions, &mut inner_expr);
        expr.append(&mut for_expr);
        Ok(())
    }
```

Comment: here a link [mcve]

Comment: Is the function that requires `&mut Vec<(&A, &mut B)>` written by you, or otherwise under your control? Its signature places severe limitations on how you can call it.

Comment: I wrote both. I will change the signature if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You put your references into the list `loop_var_with_expressions`, it means that the values these references point at must leave at least as long as this list.

In your case the first value of tuple is dropped right after the reference is pushed to the list, and the `loop_expr` value is dropped at the end of the loop cycle. So both references are invalid at the time they are used.

To make your code work, you will have to create a struct (for example a `Vec<(FeelValue, CompiledExpression)>` that would outlive your `loop_var_with_expressions`, put your values into this struct, and references the values in the structure.

Comment: I don't think the suggestion from the last paragraph would actually work, since the OP needs _mutable_ references to `CompiledExpression`. If the values are all stored in, say, a vector, you can't have mutable references to different elements of the same vector. What might work is something like `Vec<(FeelValue, RefCell<CompiledExpression>)>`, with mutable references obtained by `borrow_mut()`ing each individual refcell.

Comment: I might be able to rewrite the target function to use RefCells. I will give it a try.